# Import js file in webpack / babel-loader not working in ios9 (ipad)

Tags: javascript, ios, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I run a cordova / Vue.js app with webpack

in my package.json :

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0"
...
}
```

in my webpack.config file :

```
const CONFIG = {

    entry: {
        app: ["babel-polyfill",  path.join(PATHS.SRC_JS, 'app.js')], 
    },


    output: {
        path: PATHS.DIST,
        //filename: 'app.bundle.js'
        filename: './js/[name].js' //
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            ...
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(swiper)\/).*/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'eslint-loader',
                        options: {
                            emitWarning: true,
                            noConsole: 0 
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: [ 'env']

                        }
                    }
                ]
            },


            //.VUE FILES
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            }
        ]
    },




};


module.exports = CONFIG;
```

and in my main app.js file, 
if i write

```
console.log('app.js')
import style from '../css/sass/main.scss';
import config from '../assets/config.json';
```

and then i run webpack and cordova compilation, with output on ipad mini, it works, i have 'app.js' writed on console.

But if i add an import to js file (any file) :

```
import style from '../css/sass/main.scss';
import Preloader from './components/preloader-component.js';
import config from '../assets/config.json';
```

on ipad console i have an error :

```
SyntaxError : Unexpected token ')' in app.js:1
```

When building app with xcode on ios simulator, it works, but not on ipad (ios 9.3.5).

Need help !
Thanks

---

**RESOLVED**

Finally the problem was that Babel did not transpile ES6 correctly, so Safari on iOS would not read the code... 
I simply put babel options in a .babelrc file, in place of in the webpack config file..and it works !!
Mysterious...
If someone has the same problem..